# Puppeteer slowMo option in selenium web driver?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

There is one option to add a delay in every action

> Slow it down - the slowMo option slows down Puppeteer operations by
>   the specified amount of milliseconds. It's another way to help see
>   what's going on.

I am trying to find a similar way in  Selenium WebDriver (I am using the ruby library).

Issue: Right now when I run Selenium script it finishes very quickly I want it to be run like human behavior. Is there any way to achieve this in Selenium??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the magic method, it is more effective as we can put random sleep between every command to make simulation like human

```
module Selenium::WebDriver::Remote
  class Bridge
    def execute(command, opts = {}, command_hash = nil)
      verb, path = commands(command) || raise(ArgumentError, "unknown command: #{command.inspect}")
      path = path.dup

      path[':session_id'] = session_id if path.include?(':session_id')

      begin
        opts.each { |key, value| path[key.inspect] = escaper.escape(value.to_s) }
      rescue IndexError
        raise ArgumentError, "#{opts.inspect} invalid for #{command.inspect}"
      end

      Selenium::WebDriver.logger.info("-> #{verb.to_s.upcase} #{path}")
      res = http.call(verb, path, command_hash)
      sleep rand(0.1..0.8).round(2) # <--- Add your sleep here.
      res
    end
  end
end
```